# Select * with distinct and max date in MS sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have a question about to select all data with distinct item column and max date column.

[image: table itemprice]

Based on figure above(table itemprice), item '010070056001' has 3 row with different effect_date and others column. My question are how can i select all column, in the same time i distinct 'item' column and the effect_date must be the max?

Comment: Values in column brk_cost##1 for item 010070056001 is different. So you could not distinct into a single row. Go with **group by** .

Comment: It depends a little on which RDBMS you're using but either way, lots of answers, some of which are correct

Comment: @PriVictor i just want to distinct item column and make sure after distinct the effect_date must be the latest(max)

Comment: use 'group by' and 'having' clauses. 'groupby' groups the rows with itemid and having clause used to filter the max effect date.  i.e., having max(effect_date).

Comment: Select item, vend_num, effect_date, brk_qty##1, brk_qty##2, brk_qty##3, brk_qty##4, brk_qty##5, min(brk_cost##1)
from itemprice 
group by item, vend_num, effect_date, brk_qty##1, brk_qty##2, brk_qty##3, brk_qty##4, brk_qty##5
having max(effect_date);

Comment: Have you tried a GROUP BY and MAX()?

Comment: @Adrian i've tried group by and max like this,
"select item , max(effect_date) as effect_date
from itemvendprice_mst
group by item" but how can i select * with GROUP BY AND MAX()??

Comment: SELECT all the columns you need and GROUP BY all your non-aggregate columns should work.